# How to list only printers in JavaFX Print Dialog?

Tags: printing, javafx-8

Is it possible to list only printers in the JavaFX Print Dialog ?

example for use of Print Dialog :

```
...
final PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
ret = printJob.showPrintDialog(owner);
...
```

Thank you in advance

Fabrice

Comment: hmm ... I doubt that it's possible: (on win at least) it's the native dialog, nothing much to do about it

Comment: Thank you for your response